# How do I fix the following phpcs error in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpcs

I am new to VS code. I am trying to work with PHP, but I keep getting this notification.

> phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message:unable to
>   locate phpcs. please add phpcs to your global path or use composer
>   dependency manager to install it in your project locally.

Intellisense doesn't work for PHP too.
I am using a Windows system. I tried to download and install Composer, but I am still getting the problem as shown in the screenshot.

[image: [screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyCNu.jpg)

I have some extensions installed which are visible in the screenshot, but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you install phpcs, if so how

Comment: yes i installed the recommended php extension pack but the msg is again the same

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to use composer to install phpcs globally and symlink the binary into your path;

Assuming you have composer installed and are using osx or linux (if not, follow instructions from here: [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)) then install phpcs globally: open your terminal and type:

```
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
```

You will then need to make sure phpcs is in your path. The easiest way is to symlink into /usr/local/bin. open your terminal and type:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs /usr/local/bin/phpcs
```

Comment: how do i enter these values sir. i mentioned that i am a new user i cant handel it that easy plz guide me

Comment: i am using a windows system and downloaded the composer as you mentioned and installed it but the message is same

Comment: Hi, that wasnt in the original question, but the same applies (albeit with different commands) unfortunately Im not a windows user, so dont know where composer installs by default on those systems and dont know how to alter the path in the windows terminal

Comment: thanks a lot sir for your cooperation and time you have given me to resolve the issue i apologize for not mentioning clearly the issue.

Comment: i can simply make a request that you plz do a favour and search that for me as i am a new beginner of VS code as well as coding and a net user it is difficult for me to find the appropriate solution

Comment: i have modified the original question with a new complete picture please look at that and then plz check it